# How to implement a sidebar menu appearing from the right to the left on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I know that I can use `Drawer` for left side menu but how can I customise it for the right side. I need two menus on both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use endDrawer 
You can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
endDrawer: Drawer(
        elevation: 16.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text("xyz"),
              accountEmail: Text("xyz@gmail.com"),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text("xyz"),
              ),
              otherAccountsPictures: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text("abc"),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("All Inboxes"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.mail),
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        elevation: 16.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text("xyz"),
              accountEmail: Text("xyz@gmail.com"),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text("xyz"),
              ),
              otherAccountsPictures: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text("abc"),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("All Inboxes"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.mail),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 0.1,
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Primary"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.inbox),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Social"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.people),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Promotions"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.local_offer),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        elevation: 16.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text("xyz"),
              accountEmail: Text("xyz@gmail.com"),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text("xyz"),
              ),
              otherAccountsPictures: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text("abc"),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("All Inboxes"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.mail),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 0.1,
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Primary"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.inbox),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Social"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.people),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Promotions"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.local_offer),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `endDrawer, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/endDrawer.html

```
Scaffold(
   endDrawer:populateDrawer()
);
```

and here is the `populateDrawer()`

```
  populateDrawer() {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.white),
      child: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Center(
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/lf_logo.png",
                    height: 100, width: 100),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(color: Configuration.PrimaryColor),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.access_time),
              title: Text('Your Activity'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ActivityPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
              title: Text('Change Password'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ChangepasswordPage(userId: userId),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.feedback),
              title: Text('Feedback'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => FeedbackPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.map),
              title: Text('Address Lists'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => AddAddress(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 50,
              color: Configuration.PrimaryColor,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
              title: Text('Privacy And Policy'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => PrivacyPolicy(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              title: Text('Logout'),
              onTap: () {
                logout();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```